# DependencyProperty Silverlight UserControl

Tags: c#, silverlight, user-controls, dependency-properties

I have read through a few articles on this and I can't see what im doing wrong here could anyone help :)

I have a UserControl called CreateRuleItemView I want to add a Dependency Property on here that I can bind my ViewModel too. So far I have.

```
public partial class CreateRuleItemView : UserControl
{
    public CreateRuleItemView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Boolean ShowEditTablePopup
    {
        get
        {

            return (Boolean)this.GetValue(ShowEditTablePopupProperty);
        }
        set
        {

            this.SetValue(ShowEditTablePopupProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ShowEditTablePopupProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ShowEditTablePopup", typeof(Boolean), typeof(CreateRuleItemView), new PropertyMetadata(null, OnShowEditTablePopupChanged));

    private static void OnShowEditTablePopupChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    }

}
```

If I then try to access the property in the User Control Xaml I get:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Views.Setup.CreateRuleItemView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=vm:CreateRuleItemViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=False}"         
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400" ShowEditTablePopup="{Binding DataContext.ShowEditTablePopup}" >
```

Error   1   The member "ShowEditTablePopup" is not recognized or is not accessible.

Error   3   The property 'ShowEditTablePopup' does not exist on the type 'UserControl'

Error   2   The property 'ShowEditTablePopup' was not found in type 'UserControl'.

**Edit 1**:
Ok Managed to get around this by adding the binding in the code behind on my Main window where i setup my view.

```
Setup.CreateRuleItemView v = new Setup.CreateRuleItemView();  
BindingOperations.SetBinding(v, CreateRuleItemView.EditTablePopupProperty, new Binding("EditTablePopup"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to achieve this with a `UserControl` (I've just tried replacing the `<UserControl...` partial declaration in XAML with `<local:CreateRuleItemView` when recreating the code locally, but this results in a circular reference and thus won't compile/will potentially result in a `XamlParseException`). I'd write a control inheriting from `ContentControl` to which you can add the property and template it instead (I did this with WPF so the namespaces may differ, otherwise the code will work):

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace DepPropTest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Description of CreateRuleItemView.
    /// </summary>
    public class CreateRuleItemView : ContentControl
    {
        public CreateRuleItemView()
        {
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ShowEditTablePopupProperty = 
            DependencyProperty.Register("ShowEditTablePopup", typeof (bool), typeof (CreateRuleItemView), new PropertyMetadata());

        public bool ShowEditTablePopup
        {
            get { return (bool) GetValue(ShowEditTablePopupProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ShowEditTablePopupProperty, value); }
        }

    }
}
```

Then you can use it as follows (this example uses WPF by the way, hence `Window` being the parent control):

```
<Window x:Class="DepPropTest.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DepPropTest"
    Title="DepPropTest" Height="300" Width="300">

    <local:CreateRuleItemView Width="300"
                              Height="300"
                              ShowEditTablePopup="True">
        <local:CreateRuleItemView.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <!-- define your control's visual appearance... -->
            </ControlTemplate>
        </local:CreateRuleItemView.Template>

        <TextBox Text="Some content for your view" />
    </local:CreateRuleItemView>
</Window>
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for that I will look into this. I have managed to get around this for now adding the Binding in Code when I Assign my View.

Comment: Cool, let me know how you get on.